# Emacs, Objective-C, and autocomplete

Tags: objective-c, emacs, autocomplete

I recently switched to emacs for my code editing, and it mostly works well.

However, for Objective-C I find myself missing Xcode's autocomplete feature as I have trouble remembering the long function names such as

```
- (id)initWithContentRect:(NSRect)contentRect styleMask:(NSUInteger)windowStyle backing:(NSBackingStoreType)bufferingType defer:(BOOL)deferCreation screen:(NSScreen *)screen;
```

Is there a way to get Xcode-style autocompletion on emacs?

Also, are there any good packages to help with Cocoa or Objective-C in general that I should have?

Comment: I would note that you can use Emacs keybindings in Xcode so you get some of the advantages of Emacs within Xcode.

Comment: Untagging cocoa, since it's a lot more relevant to Objective-C, and because "Cocoa autocomplete" is something entirely different.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a script to export function definitions in Cocoa SDK as yasnippet snippets: http://github.com/zegal/yasobjc

With the help with ETAGS and auto-complete, the completion experience is very close to XCode. You can have a try.

Comment: Very clever, and super useful, I love it ! Thanks zegal

Comment: Nice work! However, I wonder if it is possible to tie this into Semantic? If I know the message name, yasnippet+yasobjc are fine for completing, but what if I need to find the correct message first? Semantic could determine the type of the object in question, and present valid messages from the yasnippets.

Answer (score 5):

A somewhat buggy and hacky, but very nice solution is `clang-completion-mode.el` found in the [clang svn](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html#build).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used XCode, but emacs comes with several autocomplete modes.

See:

- built in dabbrev-expand (M-/ runs the command dabbrev-expand which "autocompletes" partially written text)
- [AutoComplete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete)
- [HippieExpand](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HippieExpand)

Also [cedet](http://cedet.sourceforge.net/) for something more sophisticated - but I don't think it works with objective-c unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure any of these will work well enough though (doesn't look like any are context sensitive enough), I think I may just stick to XCode for Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it yet, but company-mode has an xcode backend that could be quite helpful:

http://nschum.de/src/emacs/company-mode/

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `auto-complete.el` (look for it in the folder you installed *"auto-complete"* package, of course):

Goto line 165, I guarantee you know what to do already. :)

Comment: I prefer the `M-x` customize-variable `RET` ac-mode `RET`. Or even better in you .emacs add `(setq ac-mode (cons 'objc-mode ac-mode))`