# Setting Up Objective-C with Kdevelop

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know how to setup Objective-C with KDevelop? I've been searching and searching for a supposed "patch", which is supposed to integrate support in with the IDE, yet I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: Question, why would you like to do that instead of using XCode?

Comment: Perhaps Holland wants to use Objective-C in Linux?

Comment: That's exactly the reason why. I don't have a mac.

Comment: When you get an answer from the GNUStep list as NSResponder suggested, please consider coming back here and posting your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go to GnuStep.org, and ask this question on their mailing list.  They're the guys who do the most obj-c development on Linux that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

This has been partially [treated on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67640/other-than-xcode-are-there-any-full-functioned-ides-for-objective-c) already. Apart from the discussion over there, I sometimes use Emacs besides Xcode. I use Emacs for most of my editing and coding needs, and it comes with a nice Objective-C mode. Autocompletion in Xcode is the big selling point, but I just found out there is [an answer on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668732/emacs-objective-c-and-autocomplete) as well. I haven't tried it yet, but it might be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also interesting in developing on Linux using Objective-C.  Due to the success of the language on Apple platforms, there are an increasing number of skilled Objective-C Developers whose efforts could benefit OSS if only the gap in Linux tooling were closed.

GNUstep is a fantastic effort and, along with LLVM and Clang, goes much of the way to achieving this. But: there is no modern IDE which supports Objective-C in Linux.  ProjectCenter is the official GNUstep IDE but honestly it is showing its age.

JetBrains seem to be in the best position to change this situation: they are producers of the foremost Objective-C IDE for iOS: AppCode, and have just released a C/C++ IDE for Linux called CLion.  If enough interest is shown, perhaps they would consider integrating Objective-C support from AppCode into CLion.  Compiling against GNUstep, this would breathe new life into cross-platform Objective-C development.

I would encourage anyone interested in this possibility, to sign into JetBrains request tracker and vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-3353